# Paperclip + AWS S3, Prefixing remote path with my local path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip with a Rails 4 app and Amazon S3 storage. On my development machine, the site is running at

```
/Users/Jeff/Sites/example.com/web
```

When I upload a file with Paperclip to S3, the remote path in S3 inherits my local folder structure.

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/example_com_bucket/Users/Jeff/Sites/example.com/web/public/assets/uploads/my_class/8/medium/some_image.png?1383060287
```

Why is this happening? How do I strip that part out? I tried changing the `:path` property but that only seemed to affect the "application" part of the path (e.g. after `/assets/uploads`) My site is still in development, so I don't care about having to preserve links.

My config is...

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => 'example_com_bucket',
      :access_key_id => '...',
      :secret_access_key => '...'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried omitting the :path setting? Another idea maybe: try using the :url setting? Here's what Thoughtbot suggests configuring: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue when I was using the `:url` parameter where I should have been using the `:path` parameter:

```
has_attached_file :primary_photo,
                    :styles => ...,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
                    :s3_credentials => 'config/s3.yml',
                    :url => '/product/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename'
```

I fixed it by changing my config to this:

```
has_attached_file :primary_photo,
                    :styles => ...,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
                    :s3_credentials => 'config/s3.yml',
                    :path => '/product/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename'
```