# Paperclip unable to change default path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, spree

I'm having a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662695/paperclip-aws-s3-prefixing-remote-path-with-my-local-path) issue, except I'm unable to modify the path at all.

I'm using Spree 2.2 which uses paperclip 3.4.2

I'm trying to modify the paperclip defaults to change the image path.  All of the other configuration is working.

```
Myapp::Application.configure do
  config.paperclip_defaults = { 
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_protocol => 'https',
    :s3_host_name => "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
    :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => 'xxx',
      :access_key_id => "xxx",
      :secret_access_key => "xxx"
    }   
  }     
end
```

But with this code the URL is like so:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/home/username/path/to/project/public/spree/products/24/original/ror_baseball.jpeg?1390110939

I've tried adding the following to that config block:

```
config.attachment_path = '/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
```

I've also tried adding the following to the config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

And also tried:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
  :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
)
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: [opened ticket on github](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4448)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Spree 2.2 (not 2.1), use the following code in initializers/spree.rb:

```
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:url] = ':path'
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:path] = '/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
```

The rest of the configuration should be set as 2.1 (see [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4448) for details).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the /home/username/path/to/project/ part is being added by the :rails_root portion of your :path configuration.

If you look at the source code at:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb

You will see that the default values are as follows:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public:url",
:url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
```

What if you set the following:

```
:path => ":url",
:url => "/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
```

Let me know what these do for you and we can see what else you need to do in order to get this working properly.

Comment: Actually the problem is that it doesn't seem to be using the path and url configuration options.  I can put anything in there and nothing changes.  I haven't been able to find anywhere else in my configuration where the path and url might be being overridden.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize that your path didn't include a folder named spree but the generated url did.  Sorry about that, my second answer should help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick Google search, prompted by your comment I figured it out.  I believe the answer is here, in the Spree documentation:

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/configuring_images.html

UPDATE:  Apparently This is only available on older versions.  In newer versions, it looks like you need to override Spree::Image. This is defined in vendor/bundle/gems/spree_core-2.2.0/app/models/spree/image.rb.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe this documentation is old and does not apply to Spree 2.2.  They've removed the built-in S3 integration and it's done only through Paperclip now.  A default installation of Spree 2.2 does not even have the images configuration page.

Comment: Hmm, that is the only place I can think of that would override your paperclip configuration.  The URL you pasted also matches what that doc shows as their default configuration.  Sorry I couldn't help, maybe their support team can help you.

Comment: Yeh I've opened a ticket on github: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4448.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: I figured out where this is defined.  It looks like you need to override Spree::Image.  This is defined in vendor/bundle/gems/spree_core-2.2.0/app/models/spree/image.rb.

Comment: Yeh I just found that, thanks!  It's working using settings like this: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4448#issuecomment-37734007.  But I don't know if this is a bug or not.  Waiting to see what the Spree devs say.

Comment: I updated this solution.  If you feel this answer was the correct one for you....please accept my answer :-)